# python3 - behaviour of super() on multi-inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, superclass, super

I know that super() and multi-inheritance have already been discussed here. But I did not find a solution, regarding my specific problem in python3.
Let's assume we have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("The")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("world")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("is")

class D(A,C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("nice")

d = D()

d.foo()
```

This will get me:

```
The
nice
```

On the other hand, if I change the order of inheritance in D() to:

```
class D(C,A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("nice")
```

It gives me

```
world
is
nice
```

I, however, only get the desired output:

```
The
world
is
nice
```

using:

```
class D(C,A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        A.foo(self)
        C.foo(self)
        print("nice")
```

Which I find quite unelegant.

So my question is: Is it possible to use super() in python3 invoking the super method of **both** super classes instead of just the first?

Comment: There is no *both* here. `super()` works with *the next base class in MRO order*. There is only ever **one** such class.

Comment: So, in the latter case, the superclass of __D__ would be just __C__? What's with __A__ then, anyway? 
It obviously causes super() to change its behaviour changing the order of the classes inherited by __D__.

Comment: Take a look at `D.__mro__`; that is the order methods are looked up in. `super()` takes that list and finds the 'current' class (where the method is defined) in that list, then starts searching for your requested attribute at the next item in that list.

Comment: For `D(A,C)` the order is `(D, A, C, B, object)`. For `D(C,A)` the order is `(D, C, B, A, object)`. So `super().foo()` in `C.foo()` finds `B.foo()` in both cases, but in `D.foo()` it'll either be `A` that comes next, or `C`. Adjust your other `foo` functions accordingly.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, it simply is not possible to invoke more than one superclass' method of the same name using `super()` in multiple inheritance?

Comment: You'd have to explicitly tell `super()` to start searching the MRO elsewhere: `super(A, self)` would tell it to start searching past `A`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, without a knowledge of the method resolution order (MRO) of `D`, there is no way to call `super()` in `D` to get at *both* base classes.

But the MRO is powerful concept. In the second case,

```
class D(C,A):
    ...
```

the (MRO) is

```
>>> D.mro()
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Inasmuch as calling `super()` takes you to the next class in the MRO, as Mr. Pieters stated, and you want the print statements coming in the order of `A`, `B`, `C`, then `D`, simply put `super().foo()` first and `print(...)` second in each definition of `foo()`.  The only exception is do not put `super().foo()` in class `A` because `foo()` is not defined in `object`.

#### Solution

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("The")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()      # Inserted
        print("world")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("is")

class D(C,A):              # Correct ordering
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("nice")

d = D()

d.foo()
```

#### Alternate solution

The MRO of `D(A,C)` in the first case includes all classes as well, so with correct ordering of `super()` and `print(...)` statements, one can make it work:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("The")
        super().foo()

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("world")

class C(B):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("is")

class D(A,C):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("nice")

D().foo()
```

#### Further reading

To understand inheritance order (e.g. `class D(C,A)` or `class D(A,C)`) and MRO, see https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/. The C3 method resolution order is described in detail and there are nicely drawn ASCII class hierarchies with the MRO labeled.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help

```
 class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("The")
        if hasattr(super(), 'foo'):
            super().foo()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("world")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("is")

class D(A,C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("nice")

d = D()

d.foo()
```

output:

```
The
world
is
nice
```