# Python : super key word calling from child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Parent01(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("Parent01")
        pass

class Parent02(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("Parent02")
        pass

class Child(Parent01,Parent02):
    def foo(self):
        print("Child")
        super(Parent01, self).foo()
    pass

c = Child()
c.foo()
```

Output:

```
Child
Parent02
```

Why here is the output `Parent02`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance). Also [Python's Multiple Inheritance: Picking which super() to call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14206015/4831822)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python3 - behaviour of super() on multi-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166225/python3-behaviour-of-super-on-multi-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). You're supposed to name your *own* class, not a parent. And given this is Python 3, you don't even need to do that, a simple:

```
super().foo()
```

would work (as long as the first parameter to the function is a single argument, regardless of name; there are exceptions for when you're accepting `self` via `*args`, but that's rare, and only for complicated cases involving simulating a `dict`).

The reason it misbehaves as written is that you've told it explicitly you're doing `super` based in `Parent01`, not `Child`, so it scans [the MRO (method resolution order)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) to find the next class after `Parent01`, which happens to be `Parent02`.