# Strange multi-inheritance in python3

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I know this question has been discussed for many times,but it seems that nobody pays attention to such a situation. Code is:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print('a',kwargs)
        super(A,self).__init__()
        print('a2',kwargs)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print('b',kwargs)
        super(B,self).__init__()
        print('b2',kwargs)

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print('c',kwargs)
        super(C,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print('c2',kwargs)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(A.__mro__)
    a=A(namea=1)
    print(B.__mro__)
    b=B(nameb=2)
    print(C.__mro__)
    c=C(namec=3)
```

The result is:

```
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
a {'namea': 1}
a2 {'namea': 1}
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
b {'nameb': 2}
b2 {'nameb': 2}
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
c {'namec': 3}
a {'namec': 3}
b {}
b2 {}
a2 {'namec': 3}
c2 {'namec': 3}
```

I found an discussion at [python3-behaviour-of-super-on-multi-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166225/python3-behaviour-of-super-on-multi-inheritance).However,they didn't involve why `A.__init__` is interrupt by `B.__init__` and why there is no `kwargs` be passed to `B.__init__`?

What is more,there still exists a problem in my multi-inheritance example,it looks like :

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def __init__():
        self.logger=logging.getLogger('')
        self.i=self.logger.info
class Spider(requests_html.HTMLSession,MyLogger):
    def __init__():
        super(Spider,self).__init__()
        self.i('hello')
```

when I run `Spider()`,the exception tells me `AttributeError: 'Spider' object has no attribute 'i'` ! But,if i exchange the position of HTMLSession and MyLogger,it works.

This is beyond my understanding,anyone helps me ,appreciate it very much!